# Pandas Filtering and Tagging Data in Given Date Range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame({'date': {10: Timestamp('2019-01-01 10:00:00'), 52: Timestamp('2019-01-03 04:00:00'), 54: Timestamp('2019-01-03 06:00:00'), 72: Timestamp('2019-01-04 00:00:00'), 74: Timestamp('2019-01-04 02:00:00')}, 'value_1': {10: 4380.0, 52: 4440.0, 54: 4630.0, 72: 4540.0, 74: 4460.0}, 'value_2': {10: 5, 52: 5, 54: 1, 72: 5, 74: 1}})
```

DF1

```
                  date  value_1  value_2
10 2019-01-01 10:00:00   4380.0        5
52 2019-01-03 04:00:00   4440.0        5
54 2019-01-03 06:00:00   4630.0        1
72 2019-01-04 00:00:00   4540.0        5
74 2019-01-04 02:00:00   4460.0        1
```

DF2 contains date column which is common with DF1 and start from 2019-01-01 00:00:00 and end at 2019-12-31 00:00:00 and other uncommon columns.

I've put value of values_1 from DF1 into DF2 if dates from DF1 and DF2 are matching as following code:

```
DF2['value_1'] = DF2['date'].map(DF1.set_index('date')['value_1'])
```

Now I'm trying to put same value for the last 30 mins of matched date into DF2. In other words if matched date and time lets say `2019-01-01 10:00:00` and value_1 is `4380.0`. Then value_1 column should be `4380.0` for the dates from `2019-01-01 09:30:00` to `2019-01-01 10:00:00` dates in DF2.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with default `direction='backward'` and then `direction='forward'` and combine both DataFrames by [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': {10: pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 10:00:00'), 52: pd.Timestamp('2019-01-03 04:00:00'), 54: pd.Timestamp('2019-01-03 06:00:00'), 72: pd.Timestamp('2019-01-04 00:00:00'), 74: pd.Timestamp('2019-01-04 02:00:00')}, 'value_1': {10: 4380.0, 52: 4440.0, 54: 4630.0, 72: 4540.0, 74: 4460.0}, 'value_2': {10: 5, 52: 5, 54: 1, 72: 5, 74: 1}})

#small data for test    
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2019-01-01 08:00:00', 
                                         '2019-01-01 12:00:00', freq='20Min')})
print (DF2)
                  date
0  2019-01-01 08:00:00
1  2019-01-01 08:20:00
2  2019-01-01 08:40:00
3  2019-01-01 09:00:00
4  2019-01-01 09:20:00
5  2019-01-01 09:40:00
6  2019-01-01 10:00:00
7  2019-01-01 10:20:00
8  2019-01-01 10:40:00
9  2019-01-01 11:00:00
10 2019-01-01 11:20:00
11 2019-01-01 11:40:00
12 2019-01-01 12:00:00
```

---

```
df1 = pd.merge_asof(DF2, DF1, on='date', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30Min'))
df2 = pd.merge_asof(DF2, DF1, on='date', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30Min'), direction='forward')

df = df1.combine_first(df2)
print (df)
                  date  value_1  value_2
0  2019-01-01 08:00:00      NaN      NaN
1  2019-01-01 08:20:00      NaN      NaN
2  2019-01-01 08:40:00      NaN      NaN
3  2019-01-01 09:00:00      NaN      NaN
4  2019-01-01 09:20:00      NaN      NaN
5  2019-01-01 09:40:00   4380.0      5.0
6  2019-01-01 10:00:00   4380.0      5.0
7  2019-01-01 10:20:00   4380.0      5.0
8  2019-01-01 10:40:00      NaN      NaN
9  2019-01-01 11:00:00      NaN      NaN
10 2019-01-01 11:20:00      NaN      NaN
11 2019-01-01 11:40:00      NaN      NaN
12 2019-01-01 12:00:00      NaN      NaN
```